# Uploading multiple images corrupts all but first - Flask

Tags: python, image, flask, upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images but except the first image on the file, all other images are getting corrupted during upload. I can view the first image without a problem but the rest can not be viewed. windows says `We can't open this file`. This almost sounds like the extension is unknown.

On the side note, when I look at the details of one of the corrupted images all fields are empty except at the bottom, the filename and such.

```
# view.py 
@myVacation_blueprint.route('/logVacation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def log_vacation():
form = LogVacationForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            # Get the image name
            uploaded_images = request.files.getlist('photo')
            for image in uploaded_images:
                filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
                # Get the extension
                extension = filename.split('.')[1]
                filename = filename.split('.')[0]
                # Concatenate filename and current time
                filename = str(filename) + str(time.time())
                # Hash the filename
                hash_file_name = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(filename).decode('utf-8')
                # Normalize
                filename = "".join([c if c.isalnum() else "" for c in hash_file_name])
                # Add the extension
                filename = filename + '.' + str(extension)
                # Save the file
                directory = _user_img_folder(form)
                print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
                form.photo.data.save(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return render_template('myVacation.html')
    else:
        filename = None
return render_template('logVacation.html', form=form, error=error)


# forms.py
class LogVacationForm(FlaskForm):
vacation_name = StringField('Vacation Name', validators=[DataRequired(),   Length(min=6, max=25)])
location = StringField('Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
with_who = StringField('With_Who')
description = TextAreaField('Description', render_kw={
    'class': 'vacation_description',
    'rows': 10
})
photo = FileField('Select Images', validators=[
    # FileRequired(),
    FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only')],
                  render_kw={'multiple': True}
                  )

# logVacation.html

# many lines....
<form class="logVacation" enctype=multipart/form-data role="form" method="post" action="/logVacation">
# Some other input
{{ form.photo(multiple="multiple") }}
# Some other input
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="upload" type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

What am I missing here?

**NOTE:** I've just noticed that at `view.py` the value of `form.photo.data` never changes after the first image name. So apparently it's not receiving the data for the other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you use `form.validate_on_submit()`, then `if request.method == 'POST'` can be removed.
- the `.save()` method's object is file stream (`image`), instead of form data (`form.photo.data`).

Just like this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    for image in request.files.getlist('photo'):
        ...
        image.save(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```